# How to call expression result after paste command in R?

Tags: r

I want to get a cell value after dynamically passing its address. So I am trying paste command to join the address of the cell like following:

```
paste0("DT1$", eval(cols[1]),"[1]")
```

where DT1 is datatable, cols[1] is refering to 1 column and [1] is first row of that column. While running this I am getting the string(address of the cell):

```
> paste0("DT1$", eval(cols[1]),"[1]")
[1] "DT1$BCC1[1]"
```

But I want the value of the cell like if I run:

```
> DT1$BCC1[1]
[1] 0
```

So how to run call the result of the paste expression to get value of cell like "0" in previous example. I tried eval() and do.call(), but nothing seems to be working. I am sorry for this basic question as I am new to R. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use eval(), but you have to parse the string "DT1$BCC1[1]" first:

```
str <-paste0("DT1$", eval(cols[1]),"[1]")
eval(parse(text = str))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$` dollar is suitable for console use(partial name matching). You should Use the subsetting `[` operator.

For example you can call it like this :

```
DT1[1,cols[1]]
```

Ore more general :

```
x= 1
y = "BCC1"
DT1[x,y]
```

Note that DT1 that here is a `data.frame` not a `data.table`.  You can do the same thing with a `data.table`:

```
DT1[x,y,with=F]
```

Comment: Thanks so much I incorporated your suggestion in the code. Now I am using subset operator.